Cannot boot after power outage
I cannot boot Ubuntu and it guides me to initramfs. Here is the diagnosis output after checking it using disc rescue:
============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => Syslinux MBR (5.00 and higher) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  SYSLINUX 6.04
    Boot sector info:  Syslinux looks at sector 32832 of /dev/sdb1 for its 
                       second stage. The integrity check of Syslinux failed. 
                       No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /syslinux.cfg 
                       /efi/BOOT/grubx64.efi /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi /ldlinux.sys


================================ 0 OS detected =================================


================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: NVIDIA Corporation Intel Corporation from NVIDIA Corporation Intel Corporation
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS, focal, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: 1.4.3(1.4) from Dell Inc.
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 0002
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0002,0001
Boot0001* UEFI: KXG60PNV2T04 NVMe KIOXIA 2048GB HD(1,GPT,57ca3f2a-243a-4e71-93af-697d9151c172,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\Boot\BootX64.efi)..BO
Boot0002* UEFI: KingstonDataTraveler 3.0PMAP    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(20,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x851054,0x800,0x39bf800)..BO


============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, no-os, no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sda : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sda : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sda : maybesepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 1.84 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk identifier: 67239DDD-7B49-4760-AE73-D3AD032C83F2
Disk sdb: 28.9 GiB, 31004295168 bytes, 60555264 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x00851054
     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
sdb1  *     2048 60555263 60553216 28.9G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:2000GB:scsi:512:4096:gpt:ATA ST2000DM008-2FR1:;
sdb:31.0GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:Kingston DataTraveler 3.0:;
1:1049kB:31.0GB:31.0GB:fat32::boot, lba;

Free space >10MiB: ______________________________________________________________

sda: 0.02MiB:1907729MiB:1907729MiB

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL       PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                   
sdb                                                                                                   
└─sdb1 vfat     D4DB-4C5C                            00851054-01                          UBUNTU 20_0 

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                       Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1              24.8G  14% /cdrom

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/sdb1              vfat            ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro

====================== sdb1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Ubuntu
Ubuntu (safe graphics)
OEM install (for manufacturers)
Boot from next volume
UEFI Firmware Settings

========================= sdb1/syslinux.cfg (filtered) =========================

DEFAULT loadconfig

LABEL loadconfig
  CONFIG /isolinux/isolinux.cfg
  APPEND /isolinux/

==================== sdb1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1

================== sdb1: Location of files loaded by Syslinux ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             syslinux.cfg                                   1
            ?? = ??             ldlinux.sys                                    1

Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would not act on the boot.


Please show the initramfs output in your question.
